# data not accepted on php side while being transferred with get request through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
var myData = 'name='+j; //build a post data structure
alert(myData);
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "response1.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
          ......
```

when I alert the data client side it shows proper value but when I transfer it to php it does not show any value. php is as follows

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_POST["name"]) && strlen($_POST["name"])>0)
     {
      $name = $_POST["name"]);
      echo $name;
      }
    ?>
```

pls help

Answer (score 1):

you are not doing a GET, but a POST request as you defined in this line:

```
    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
```

and you need a correct key-value pair in the `data` part either way:

```
//var myData = 'name='+j; //build a post data structure
//alert(myData);
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "response1.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:{ name : j }, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
          ......
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. If I do this then control is not going on the php page and success function of ajax is also not getting invoked.

Comment: @user3293306 then you got another problem - because this will definitely work. what does your console (F12 on most browsers to show it) say?

Comment: <html><head></head><body>Array
(
)
</body></html>

Comment: @user3293306 what's that? you must not output html-code on your php-page in order to reply to an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Your values are sent as one variable. You have to access them from within that variable.

Try:

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_POST['myData']["name"]) && strlen($_POST['myData']["name"])>0)
     {
      $name = $_POST['myData']["name"]);
      echo $name;
      }
    ?>
```

If this doesn't work, `print_r()` the contents of `$_POST` in your php file to see how they are received.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I did as you suggested. print_r() on post is returning blank array Array().

Comment: add to your php file as first command `return "function response";` and check `response` in your `ajax success` code. Just to be sure the actual file is used.